# When reading in an adjacency list for a graph in Java, how do I avoid duplicate edges?

Tags: java, graph

I have a .txt file that represents a graph adjacency list. It has 200 rows, and looks like this: First column represents the vertex ID's, and each corresponding row is the list of other vertices that vertex shares an edge with.

```
1   37  79  164 155 32  87  39  113 15  18  78  175 140 200 4   160 97  191 100 91  20  69  198 196 
2   123 134 10  141 13  12  43  47  3   177 101 179 77  182 117 116 36  103 51  154 162 128 30  
3   48  123 134 109 41  17  159 49  136 16  130 141 29  176 2   190 66  153 157 70  114 65  173 104 194 54  
4   91  171 118 125 158 76  107 18  73  140 42  193 127 100 84  121 60  81  99  80  150 55  1   35  23  93  
5   193 156 102 118 175 39  124 119 19  99  160 75  20  112 37  23  145 135 146 73  35  
6   155 56  52  120 131 160 124 119 14  196 144 25  75  76  166 35  87  26  20  32  23  
7   156 185 178 79  27  52  144 107 78  22  71  26  31  15  56  76  112 39  8   113 93  
8   185 155 171 178 108 64  164 53  140 25  100 133 9   52  191 46  20  150 144 39  62  131 42  119 127 31  7   
9   91  155 8   160 107 132 195 26  20  133 39  76  100 78  122 127 38  156 191 196 115 
10  190 184 154 49  2   182 173 170 161 47  189 101 153 50  30  109 177 148 179 16  163 116 13  90  185 
11  123 134 163 41  12  28  130 13  101 83  77  109 114 21  82  88  74  24  94  48  33  
12  161 109 169 21  24  36  65  50  2   101 159 148 54  192 88  47  11  142 43  70  182 177 179 189 194 33  
13  161 141 157 44  83  90  181 41  2   176 10  29  116 134 182 170 165 173 190 159 47  82  111 142 72  154 110 21  103 130 11  33  138 152 
14  91  156 58  122 62  113 107 73  137 25  19  40  6   139 150 46  37  76  39  127 
15  149 58  68  52  39  67  121 191 1   45  100 18  118 174 40  85  196 122 42  193 119 139 26  127 145 135 57  38  7
```

I'm trying to read this file into some Java classes I made, but I'm not sure how to avoid reading in duplicate edges. For each edge, there are two numbers associated with it in the .txt file. Ex. in row #8, there's a number 9 that represents an edge shared by vertices 8 and 9. Then in row 9 there's a number 8 that represents that same edge shared by 9 and 8.

I'm using this code with a BufferedReader to make each line into an array and then add a new edge for each non-first-column vertex ID.

```
 

    private static UndirectedGraph constructGraph(String filename) throws IOException {
           
     UndirectedGraph graph = new UndirectedGraph();
    
    //count # of lines in the .txt file and make that many vertices
            int numLines = countLines("/home/paris/Downloads/kargercut.txt");
    
            for (int i = 0; i<=numLines; i++) {
                graph.addVertex(i);
    
            }
            
    //BufferedReader to make each row in .txt file into a split string array, from which I can parse Integers
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/paris/Downloads/kargercut.txt"));
            String s;
            ArrayList<String> vtxIDArray = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] sArray;
            
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                sArray = s.split(" ");
    
                for (int i = 1; i <= sArray.length - 1; i++) {
                graph.addEdge(Integer.parseInt(sArray[0]), Integer.parseInt(sArray[i]));  /*addEdge takes two vertex ID's as arguments and creates an edge in memory in all three of the aforementioned locations: one in each Vertex object, and one in the entire graph's "edgeList" ArrayList. */      
            
    }
    
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(graph.getVertexIDs()));
            
            br.close();
    
            return graph;
        }
```

My UndirectedEdge class:

```
public class UndirectedEdge {

    private Vertex end1;
    private Vertex end2;

    UndirectedEdge(Vertex end1, Vertex end2) {
        this.end1 = end1;
        this.end2 = end2;

    }

    public Vertex getEnd1() {
        return end1;
    }

    public Vertex getEnd2() {
        return end2;
    }

    public void setEnd1(Vertex end1) {
        this.end1 = end1;
    }

    public void setEnd2(Vertex end2) {
        this.end2 = end2;
    }
}
```

The addEdge method:

```
public void addEdge(Integer end1ID, Integer end2ID) {

        Vertex end1 = findVertex(end1ID);
        Vertex end2 = findVertex(end2ID);

        if ((end1 == null) || (end2 == null)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("1 or 2 of the endpoints don't exist.");
        }
        if (end1 == end2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No self-loops allowed");


        UndirectedEdge newEdge = new UndirectedEdge(end1, end2);
        edgeList.add(newEdge);
        end1.addEdge(newEdge);
        end2.addEdge(newEdge);

    }
```

Right now, a single edge in my program is stored in the Vertex class (of each of its endpoints), and in the master edgeList class. With the current way I'm reading this file in, for each edge, I'll have twice as many edges as I should have in each of those three locations in memory.
I have no idea what to do.

Comment: To properly answer this question, one needs to see your `Edge` class and possibly the source of `addEdge()` method.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is in the `addEdge()` method, check whether that edge already exists in your graph. You'll probably want to implement a new function in your `UndirectedGraph` class called `edgeExists(int vertex1, int vertex2)` that returns a bool indicating whether the edge you want to add between vertex1 and vertex2 already exist.

Then, call that function every time you want to add a new edge. If the edge doesn't yet exist, add it, otherwise don't.

An easy implementation of `edgeExists` would probably just check whether the vertex1 object contains vertex2 in its list of adjacencies.

Comment: The only problem with that is that this is supposed to allow for parallel edges, so more than one edge between the same two vertices. If I implement edgeExists, it will block any parallel edges from forming ,even ones that might be proper from the data.

Comment: @Jackson if parallel edges are allowed, there should be a mechanism to identify them in the adjacency list.  Is it the count? Like, if there is 8->9, 8->9, then we should expect 9->8, 9->8 too? Or something else?

Comment: @Jackson ah, sorry. Wasn't aware that parallel edges were allowed. I don't know an answer for this off the top of my head, sorry--I was thinking of a solution involving hash tables though, or something to keep track of existing edges (like a running counter of edges somehow that you can add or subtract as you encounter 'directional' edges as you parse the input)